# Question about 'Access Control' vulnerability

Tags: access

As far as I understand, access control is an insecure visibility setting of critical functions. For example, minting, setting owner, and sendTransaction or somewhat. It seems like we can just set functions as 'private' or assigning roles. I think it's easy to prevent but this exploit happens a lot. Why is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, private keyword does not protect to your function being accessed by someone else. It just determines the accessibility of your function from other functions. The reason why this is happening is that the team might not write the tests properly, but the actual thing behind exploits 99% of the time is the company does not audit the code to save money which is more costly at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. In addition to what [Recep](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/153134/124642) said, its difficult to keep track of what the right visibility should be as the project grows in complexity.

Often times access control vulnerabilities in smart contracts can still occur due to incorrect implementations, misunderstandings of security concepts, contract upgrades, as a result negligence from developers.

Take [LeetSwap exploit](https://twitter.com/blocksecteam/status/1686217464051539968) for example where the developers blindly forked another project without setting a critical function as private.

Promoting security awareness among developers developers can reduce the likelihood of unauthorized access and build more secure smart contracts.